# How to check if a buffer hidden in all tabs?

Tags: neovim, lua

As title. I want to check that a buffer is not shown in any tabs. How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffer is called "hidden" if it's

1. Loaded
2. Not shown in any window

```
:echo bufloaded(N) && win_findbuf(N)->empty()
```

or

```
:echo bufexists(N) && getbufinfo(N)[0].hidden
```

Comment: Additional one: Do you know the api to do the same in Lua(for NeoVim)? While your current one is really helpful since now I really understand `hidden` mean and I can still use NeoVim's API to write VimScript.

Comment: @job_start Neovim API is documented in `:h api.txt`. AFAIR, there's none.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: You can use the following APIs in Lua:

```lua
local is_hidden_buffer = vim.api.nvim_buf_is_loaded(buf)
                         and vim.api.nvim_buf_get_option(buf, 'buflisted')
```